# How to slideToggle() parts of menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a list menu:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
  <ul>
      <li>News
          <ul class="inner_menu">
              <li>Hi</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Bumble
          <ul class="inner_menu">
              <li>Hellos</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Scratch</li>
      <li>Snap</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want all unordered lists be hidden but slidedown/up (jquery slideToggle()) if you hover above the 'li' element in which they are nested. I am having problems with selecting the right elements. E.g. I want to slideToggle() .inner_menu with 'Hi' when I hover above "News".

So far I have been able to slideToggle() all of the .inner_menus or get different unwanted results. I think I can just add bunch of different 'id's but that would be just so messy, considering two similar menus with a lot of inner_menus.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on DOM traversal.  this would be a good place to start: http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/.  This will help you impact the correct node with each action.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely look here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `hover` in/out handler:

### DEMO jsFiddle

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: One more question. Each `li` of `.inner_menus ul` is a link. Once you click it the part next to the menu changes, but the menu stays at it's place. Assume I used `$('li').click()` instead(and firstly I hide all the `.inner_menu` ), then after I click the `News` and then `Hi`, the part of web changes, bud also the the `Hi` disappears. That's a bit odd because you would have to click it each  time. I would like it to stay in the same status, that is hidden or shown.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, update jsfiddle to replicate your issue

Comment: Well, I am using Flask and Jinja2 templates, so I can not simple updated jsFiddle:(

Comment: So I have tried to update it, the problem is, I don't want the `.inner_menus` to slideUp after you click on the links. http://jsfiddle.net/8Mhrw/3/